# Open set of links in different tabs using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to write a short scrip, which will help me open links from the list in separate browser tabs using Selenium/Python.

Here is the sample of my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Opera()
driver.get(https://www.google.com/)
links = ['link_1', 'link_2', 'link_3']
for link in links:
    # open a new tab
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
    driver.get(link)
```

I using Opera 67.
Somehow, the combination of keys Control + t doesn't work, pages are being opened one after another in the same tab. Any hint will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to open new tab, you can use `.execute_script` like below:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
links = ['link_1', 'link_2', 'link_3']
for link in links:
    # open a new tab
    driver.execute_script("window.open('" +link +"');")
```